# Download code from GitHub using octokit.net

Tags: c#, git, github-api, octokit

I want to download code from public and private repository from GitHub. For this purpose I choosed octokit.net, but i have big problem to understand how I should use this lib to achieve my goal. Generally it should be done via new GitHubClient class. But when I'm trying to download code octokit.net I'm getting error that path is wrong.

```
var github = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("OctokitTests"), new Uri("https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net.git);
var repository = await github.Repository.Get("onwer", "user");
```

Comment: You need get auth first.

Comment: Octokit is suited to fetching data from the GitHub API. If you want to download the repository code it might be easier to just clone the repository down...

Comment: Here is how to download a public or private GitHub repository code using the .NET built-in `HttpClient` class http://stackoverflow.com/a/31790435/287740

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `baseAddress` overload on `GitHubClient` is for when you need to connect to a GitHub Enterprise environment. If you're just connecting to github.com, you don't need to specify it.

```
var client = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("OctokitTests"));
var repository = await client.Repository.Get("octokit", "octokit.net");
```

Comment: Where is the code downloaded from GitHub resides?