# Read raw file contents in private repo in C#

Tags: c#, github

I want to read the contents of a private GitHub repo file and declare the value in a variable in a C# Visual Studio .NET Application. What's easiest the way of going about this?

Comment: Your question kinda reads as _["where they want to start, and where they want to end, but there are way too many pieces to fill in"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/223458/284550)_ and if so might be considered too broad.  Consider adding more information about how you would like your problem solved, perhaps with a code sample of what you have already tried.  Good luck!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the [Get Repository content API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents#get-repository-content=) from your CSharp program, assuming:

- you have a [PAT (personal-access-token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) (that you would then read from a file or an environment variable: do not add it directly in your csharp code in clear)
- you have access to the private repository
- the file does not exceed 100MB ([since May 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72108664/6309))

You can see an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45814125/6309), using `var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.github.com/repos/$OWNER/$REPO/contents/$PATH");`

For example, for a given file https://github.com/VonC/gitw/blob/master/version/version.go

- `$OWNER` would be `VonC`
- `$REPO` would be `gitw`
- `$PATH` would be `version/version.go`

As in:

`curl -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw" https://api.github.com/repos/VonC/gitw/contents/version/version.go`

Do use `application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw` in your `request.Accept`:

```
request.Accept = "application/vnd.github.VERSION.raw";
```

That way, you get the content of the file.